# Apple OSX with JVM support (or any virtual machine)

Tags: apple, java, osx-lion

Few things I didn't understand on OS X...

From 2010 until today...

- Throughout the internet there were several sources stating that according to Apple's EULA it wasn't legal to run any virtual machine (including JVM) on OS X 10.5 and above.
- As time passed, internet sources stated that JVM shipping with OS X was deprecated only and Oracle took over the updates.

Currently, is it legal to run JVM on OS X? If so, does Apple supports it?

EDIT:
All Apple's i-devices will never run JVM (at least not support it). I don't know what's the future on this issue, but it seems that there JVMs for i-devices, but are they legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the last few versions of OSX haven't shipped with a JRE but if you try to run any .jar file a message pops up and asks if you want to download one. This come from them directly and is supported by them although it's almost 100% pure Oracle code.

Answer (score 0):

It was always legal to run the JVM on MacOS. Don't confuse this with running virtual machines in VMWare Fusion or VirtualBox. With this, you could always run Windows, Linux etc. The restrictions you likely refer to apply to virtualizing MacOS X, which is allowed today under some circumstances, but only on Apple hardware and never on something else.